# c++ a method works only in main function

Tags: c++, winapi

The idea is to make inscriptionons on top of any application

I have this code in my main.cpp

```
#include "OVERLAY.h"
void notWorking(Overlay &ol)
{
    ol.addLabel(100, 100, L"ASDASDASD", RGB(255, 0, 0));
}
int main()
{

    Overlay ol;

    ol.addLabel(100, 100, L"ASDASDASD", RGB(255, 0, 0));
    //notWorking(ol);
    
    for (;;)
    {
        ol.drawAll();
    }

}
```

When I do `ol.addLabel(100, 100, L"ASDASDASD", RGB(255, 0, 0));` a label appears on the screen,
but when I call `notWorking(ol);` it appears for a split second and then gone.
Basically I can't call `addLabel()` anywhere beside my main function

Overlay class:

```
class Overlay
{
private:
    std::vector<Label> labels;
    HDC hdc;
    
public:
    void addLabel(int x, int y, std::wstring title, COLORREF clr)
    {
        Label label;
        label.create(x, y, title, hdc, clr);
        label.draw(2); 
        labels.push_back(label);
    }
    
    void drawAll()
    {   
        for (int i =0; i < labels.size(); i++)
            labels[i].draw();   
    }


    Overlay()
    {   
        hdc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());    
    }
};
```

Label class:

```
class Label
{
    int x, y;
    std::wstring txt;
    HDC* wdc;
    COLORREF color;
public:
    Label()
    {

    }
    void create(int x, int y, std::wstring text, HDC wdc, COLORREF color)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->txt = text;
        this->wdc = &wdc;
        this->color = color;
    }
    void draw(int state = 1)
    {
        RECT rect;

        SetTextColor(*wdc, color);
        
        SetBkMode(*wdc, state); 
        rect.left = x;
        rect.top = y;

        DrawText(*wdc, txt.c_str(), -1, &rect, DT_NOCLIP);
    }
};
```

I tried calling addLabel() within its class, but even then it didn't work

Comment: Why are you storing an `HDC*` pointer in `Label`? You are storing a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope when the `Label` constructor exits, leaving the pointer dangling. `HDC` is already a pointer type, so you can safely copy it around and store it by its value (as `Overlay` is doing), you don't need an extra pointer indirection.

Comment: That would appear to be the crux of the problem, since storing `&wdc` where `wdc` has function scope, then using it outside that function scope, is undefined behavior. Likely this is manifesting itself as a result of the `notWorking` call overwriting that dangling reference somewhere in the call stack.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I see nothing in this that requires two-phase initialization, so why the `create` function in `Label` rather than a smarter constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Label`, you are storing an `HDC*` pointer to an `HDC` variable that is local to the `Label` constructor, and which goes out of scope when the constructor exits, thus leaving the pointer dangling.  Any use of the `HDC*` pointer after that point is *undefined behavior*.

Which means, even the call to `addLabel()` inside of `main()` is subject to this problem.  The fact that it works at all is pure luck.

`HDC` is already a pointer type to begin with, so you can safely copy it around and store it by its value (as `Overlay` does internally).

Change `Label` to remove the extra pointer indirection on the `HDC`, eg:

```
class Label
{
    ...
    HDC wdc;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void create(..., HDC wdc, ...)
    {
        ...
        this->wdc = wdc;
        ...
    }
    void draw(...)
    {
        ...

        SetTextColor(wdc, ...);
        
        SetBkMode(wdc, ...); 
        ...

        DrawText(wdc, ...);
    }
};
```